# Changing code to run multiple linear regression models between responses and 8 predictors and saving table as one output

Tags: r, loops, regression, apply

I am unsure of how to alter my code for running linear regression models, which is currently utilising one independent variable at a time and 8 predictors, and saving the effect size, std.error and p value for each of the 8 comparisons. However, I am unsure as to how to change this such that I can run this model with each of my 48 dependent variables in an automated fashion, rather than changing the code each time and copying/pasting tables.

```
output <- apply(f1[, 330:337], 2, function(i){
fit <- lm(f1$response1 ~ i + f1$Cov1 + f1$Cov2 + f1$Cov3 + f1Cov4 
        + f1$Cov5 + f1$Cov6 + f1$Cov7 +
          f1$Cov8, data=f1,    na.action=na.omit)
 tbl <- summary(fit)$coef
 results <- c(tbl[2,1],tbl[2,2],tbl[2,4])
 })
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: My dependent variables are present in the same dataframe (f1) as the independent variables and they are columns 281:327. In downstream analyses I will have over 80 dependent variables and it would be really handy to automate this.

I would like an extension of the output I get already ( 8 nutrients are what I specify as i in the above formula).

```
             Nutrient1 Nutrient2 Nutrient3 Nutrient4 Nutrient5 Nutrient6 etc
 EffectSize
 Std.Error
 Pvalue
```

This would be the output using the code above with one dependent variable. I would like each of the 48 dependent variables run in individual models, but the output would be one 144 by 8 table in the end ( 48 effect sizes, std.errors and p values) for each of the 8 nutrients. I don't know how to alter the above code to specify my 48 dependent variables and state the running of the 48 individual linear regression models, combining the results in one table.

Comment: It's hard to understand what your initial data looks like (where the dependent and independent variables are stored), and what output you want. Could you try to provide an example of both?

Comment: @rw2 please find above edits which hopefully make it a bit clearer.

Comment: I still don't understand - are Cov1 etc the same as Nutrient 1 etc. ? Do you want to run regressions with different combinations of 8 independent variables, or with all 48 individually?

Comment: @rw2 I am hoping to run regressions with the 48 individually but using code such that my output states the effect size, std.error and p value for each of these 48 dependent variables, so I'm not running the same code 48 times, changing the dependent variable manually each time and then copying and pasting tables. The i is the 8 nutrients, the covariates are separate columns in the data frame such as age, BMI, sex etc. My output now is just a 3x8 table showing effect size (row 1), std error(row 2) and pvalue (row 3) for 1 dependent variable and the 8 independent nutrients.